# Joomla 3.3: Assign module only to frontpage

Tags: php, joomla

I would like to assign a certain module to only my frontpage in Joomla 3.3.0. With the settings offered in the Menu Assignment-section, it's almost impossible to do the trick.

When I select 'Only on the pages selected' (and only select my frontpage), it shows up on my frontpage and disappears from all the pages which are in one of the menu's. But on every page that's not assigned to any menu my module shows up too. That's strange because I just like to show it up on only the selected pages (my frontpage).

I've searched throughout the web, but I could only find some articles about this problem in older versions of Joomla. The solution would be to assign every single article to a unpublished menu. That's a lot of work as I'm going to publish several articles a day. Is there any way to do it simpler? For example by coding in the index.php of my template? Like:

```
if(JRequest::getVar('view') == "frontpage" ) {
    //You are in!
}
else {
    //You are out!
}
```

(but that code doesn't work as it's written for Joomla 1.5 or so)

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both @Lodder and @TsybaSasha 's answers are OK, but they don't answer @max's question:

You need to add additional checks to see if you are really on the frontpage. Use as many parameters as you need to be sure. For example, using Lodders method, no language:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
```

if your frontpage is a featured articles menu item, check that this is the case:

```
<?php 
$input=Jfactory::getApplication()->input; 
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault() 
&& $input->getCmd('view')=='featured' && $input->getCmd('option')=='com_content' ) {
//You are in, and will seldom fail, but could still fail if someone adds a link like
// index.php?option=com_content&view=featured&Itemid=101 where 101 is your start menu item
}
```

In a similar fashion you can add other checks: If your featured view is valid only for a specific category you could probably check this, etc.

Comment: Please be sure to mention that using `$input->getCmd('option')=='com_content'` will **only** work if you have a view from *com_content* assigned to your homepage. It will not work if you have another component assigned. Your answer is correct however adding even more check than already done is just overkill. Not to mention **if** a user ever decides to change the component assigned to the frontpage, they need to remember to update this code

Answer (score 0):

`JRequest` is deprecated so if you want to detect the frontpage, you can use the following:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
     //You are in!
}
else {
     // You are out!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: (joomla v3.5.1)

```
if (preg_match('/index\.php$/',$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
    echo "this is the homepage";
}
```

Found on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15282604/1289179 (thank you Captain Payalytic)

I did find that replacing the " with a ' I was able to add html using " as below

```
if (preg_match('/index\.php$/',$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
  echo '
    <div id="header">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="header" />
    </div>  
  ';
 }
```